# LINQ to entity VS Fluent API

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities, entity

I am trying to find out is there any difference between LINQ to entity queries and LINQ’s fluent API.

The below snippet took from the site [Reference](http://mentormate.com/blog/improving-linq-to-entities-queries/)

```
var result = from product in this.Context.Products
                     where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Name) ? product.Names.Any(name =&gt; name.Language == filter.Language &amp;&amp; name.Value.Contains(filter.Name)) : true) &amp;&amp;
                           (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.CategoryName) ? product.Category.Names.Any(name =&gt; name.Language == filter.Language &amp;&amp; name.Value.Contains(filter. CategoryName)) : true) &amp;&amp;
                           (filter.PriceLowerLimit.HasValue ? product.Price &gt;= filter.PriceLowerLimit : true) &amp;&amp;
                           (filter.PriceUpperLimit.HasValue ? product.Price &lt;= filter.PriceUpperLimit : true)
                     select product;

        return result.ToList();
```

which is nothing but fluent syntax. Can I conclude both are pointing to same context?

Comment: What do you mean by _both_ . I only see one query here.

Comment: I had given only LINQ to entity in an assumption that everyone knows what fluent syntax is.

Comment: Is the same, only two different ways of writing the same thing. Expression will be evalutated to database only when result.ToList(); is called.